# Dispalying five posts per page using pagination does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

I am trying to add pagination to my website using a library called `react-pagination-js`. I want to list 5 posts per page and change the page when the user clicks on another link generated by the library. Currently, I get all the posts in my database listed instead of just five and I don't know why. How can I fix this issue? I don't have any errors in the console. I tried to `console.log` the `posts` array and it consoled logged it twice, the first time was an empty array and then it got filed with all the data, maybe that is part of the problem.

Here is my page component that holds the rendering of the posts and the pagination component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import SecondColumn from '../SecondColumn/SecondColumn';
import Pagination from "react-pagination-js";
import axios from 'axios';

const Posts = () => {

  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const GET_POSTS_API = process.env.REACT_APP_GET_POSTS_API

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get(GET_POSTS_API);
      setPosts(res.data);
    };

    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  // Get current posts
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);

  // Change page
  const paginate = (pageNumber) => {
    if (pageNumber > 0) {
      setCurrentPage(pageNumber);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="column">
        {posts.map(post => (
          <div key={post._id} className='post'>
            <img className="post-container__image" src={post.picture} alt="avatar" />
            <div className="post-container__post">
              <div className="post-container__text">
                <h2 className="post-container__title">{post.title}</h2>
                <p className="post-container__date">{post.date}</p>
                <p className="post-info-container__text">{post.postContent.substring(0, 500) + "..."}</p>
                <Link to={`/post/${post._id}`} className="read-more-btn">
                  <button className="read-more-btn">Read more</button>
                </Link>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
        <Pagination
          currentPage={currentPage}
          currentPosts={currentPosts}
          showFirstLastPages={true}
          sizePerPage={postsPerPage}
          totalSize={posts.length}
          totalPages={posts.length}
          changeCurrentPage={paginate}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="column">
        <SecondColumn />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
};

export default Posts;
```

And my other component in which I am displaying it:

```
import React from 'react';
import Posts from '../Posts/Posts';

const FirstColumn = () => {


  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <Posts />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default FirstColumn;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I see at a first glance:
It gets all the posts listed because this is what you are doing here:

```
{posts.map(post => (...))}
```

And your posts array is only defined once, after you got the response from your fetch function.

But what you want to render is defined in:

```
const currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
```

So I suggest to try to use

```
{currentPosts.map(post => (...))}
```